# Question on limit with square roots

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am studying up on my calculus and I have found this limit and I am not sure how to approach this without using L'Hopital's Rule.  I am guessing there is an issue with my algebra. Here it is.
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x-x\sqrt{x+x^2}-x^2}}{\sqrt x}$$I am lost on this one! Please help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried please.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{1-\sqrt{x+ x^2}-x}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x-x\sqrt{x+x^2}-x^2}}{\sqrt x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{\frac{x-x\sqrt{x+x^2}-x^2}{x}}$$Then we have
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x+x^2}-x}=1$$

Comment: Duh! I feel like an idiot.  Anyways, thanks alot.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes its the simple things that we get stuck on :)